# Libreoffice spellchecker context?

Tags: libreoffice-writer

I am running the spellchecker in [Libreoffice Writer](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/writer/) (not the "check as you write", but the spellchecker-wizard tool), and it gives very little context to the individual mistakes.  I would like to see several words before and after the tagged word, but the wizard generally displays only the word, or maybe one additional word of context.  Is there a way to set the number of words before and after an "incorrect" word in the spellcheck wizard?

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.3
Desktop: XFCE 4.12
Libreoffice: 6.07.3

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open a new Libreoffice write document.
2. Type "Hello. Noice hat."
3. Hit `F7` to run the spellcheck wizard.
4. Notice that the context of the error "Noice" includes the word "hat", but not the word "Hello."

Desired behavior:

- Find a setting that the user can adjust so that the spellchecker displays the word "Hello.", or some other user-defined quantity of context.

Comment: Which version of LibreOffice? Which Operating System? Please click [edit] and expand on your configuration. Please do  not use Add Comment; instead, use [edit].

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your punctuation.  If you enter:

> Hello, noice hat.

the context window will include "Hello".  The period after "Hello" makes it a different sentence, so it is interpreted as not relevant.

I'm not aware of a setting to change that behavior, but perhaps another user is familiar with a different spell checker that shows all or most of the line of text, regardless of punctuation.